# Why are my command line utilities running so slowly on my Mac?

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix

I have just noticed that command line utilities such as `ls` (`/bin/ls`), `touch` (`/usr/bin/touch`), `cat` (`/bin/cat`), etc. are very slow when I run them from Terminal or iTerm on my MacBook. For example:

- `ls`'ing while in an empty directory takes 1 second (it also takes 1 second in a non-empty directory, both with lots of files or with a few files);
- `touch`'ing a new file takes 1 second (it also takes 1 second to `touch` an existing file);
- `cat`'ing an empty file takes 1 second (there is also a 1 second lag before anything happens when I `cat` a non-empty file).

I have tried to diagnose this in many ways but to no avail. I do not think this is a filesystem issue, since:

- I have run Disk Utility and it reports no problems.
- Everything seems to be working just fine in Finder, e.g. directory contents are shown instantaneously in Finder.
- I installed GNU coreutils using Homebrew and tried using `gls`, `gtouch`, `gcat`, etc., and all of the operations I listed above happen instantaneously when run with the GNU version instead.

Any ideas on what could be going on? Any ideas on how to fix this?

---

**EDIT:** When I reboot the computer, or try a different user, these issues go away temporarily, but after a few minutes they seem to reappear again. Another strange thing that I noticed:

```
$ time date
Wed Jan 28 10:07:11 PST 2015

real    0m0.151s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s

$ time date
Wed Jan 28 10:07:13 PST 2015

real    0m0.029s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s

$ time date
Wed Jan 28 10:07:16 PST 2015

real    0m1.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s

$ time date
Wed Jan 28 10:07:18 PST 2015

real    0m1.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

This happens for all the utilities I've tried, `mkdir`, `scp`, `sftp`, `more`, `cat`, etc.: The first time I run it after a reboot, it's medium-slow. The second time I run it, it's sorta-fast. All subsequent times I run it, it's slow.

Comment: Can you run `time ls`, `time touch foo` etc. and copy/paste the result into your question?

Comment: @patrix: For all the cases I've listed, the `time` output is very close to real 0m1.004s, user 0m0.002s, sys 0m0.002s, plus or minus ~0.001s.

Comment: (Whereas the GNU versions have real around 0m0.004s instead)

Comment: Does something odd show up in the log (visible through Console.app) when you run these commands?

Comment: @BartArondson -- Thank you for that suggestion!! It was via the log in Console.app that I was finally able to solve the mystery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually figured out the issue today. It was caused by a piece of anti-malware software called [Sourcefire AMP (Advanced Malware Protection)](http://www.sourcefire.com/solutions/advanced-malware-protection). All of my issues went away after I disabled/uninstalled it.

I'm guessing that it was doing something like putting a delay on things in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc. for "security reasons"... I'm guessing the GNU tools were not delayed because they weren't in the "blacklisted" directories.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Feel free to accept your own answer - it may help others solving the same issue.

Comment: The www.sourcefire.com page isn’t working

www.sourcefire.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 503

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would check is that you don't have some odd $PATH - run timings of a file that doesn't exist and one that should be speedy:

```
Mac:~ bmike$ time /bin/ls /private/xyz
ls: /private/xyz: No such file or directory

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s

Mac:~ bmike$ time /bin/ls /private/tmp
com.apple.launchd.q2QmVhsPCV    com.apple.launchd.zQ5EK6R6AZ

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.003s
```

The next thing would be to check overall system business:

```
Mac:~ bmike$ vm_stat 5
Mach Virtual Memory Statistics: (page size of 4096 bytes)
    free   active   specul inactive throttle    wired  prgable   faults     copy    0fill reactive   purged file-backed anonymous cmprssed cmprssor  dcomprs   comprs  pageins  pageout  swapins swapouts
  306160  1168138    79266    53096        0   299239   613825 20971811   345367 15995721      237  2472732      203216   1097284   328691   190541   260034   646113   623838      285   286101   299172 
  305613  1172072    79345    53098        0   295915   618898     1191        1      680        0        0      203297   1101218   328691   190541        0        0        0        0        0        0 
  306163  1188285    79345    53088        0   279370   621180     1055        0      600        0        0      203287   1117431   328682   190541        9        0        0        0        0        0 
  306039  1186031    79345    53088        0   281598   621176      729        0      293        0        0      203287   1115177   328664   190541       18        0        0        0        0        0 
^C
Mac:~ bmike$ iostat 5
          disk0       cpu     load average
    KB/t tps  MB/s  us sy id   1m   5m   15m
   31.31  12  0.35   9  4 86  1.32 1.41 1.43
    0.00   0  0.00   2  2 96  1.21 1.38 1.42
   18.40   1  0.02   5  2 93  1.20 1.38 1.42
   22.00   1  0.02   3  2 95  1.20 1.38 1.42
^C
```

Then I would quit all applications and log out all users and reboot. If you have your Mac log you in, disable that in the system preferences so you can perform a safe log in after the reboot. (Hold the shift key immediately after pressing return if you type a password to log in to your user or hold shift right after selecting your user icon if you don't have a password.)

Repeat the measurements (and optionally timing the alternate gnu tools) to know if the issue is temporary or systematic.

Comment: Also log in as guest or a new user and repeat the timing

Comment: `time /bin/ls /non/existent/directory` is slow. `time /bin/ls /bin` is slow.

Comment: I've updated my question with some more details...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @bmike said, your $PATH might have something in it which causes the shell to delay before it finds the command you're trying to run.  Besides the `date` command, `time` also should be explicitly named on the command line.

Try `/usr/bin/time /bin/date` and `time date` a few times in succession to see if there is any difference in the output.  If so, then `echo $PATH` should give you a clue as to what's causing the delay.

Comment: `time` is both a shell (bash) built-in and a binary, might be better to stick to one in all cases.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought `times` was built-in, but not `time`.  I can't make `time` stop working though, even after trashing my $PATH... so, you're probably correct.  Nevertheless, comparing the output of `times /bin/date` and `times date` might be the best option overall because `times` is unambiguous afaict.  (Interestingly, `time date`, `times date`, and `/usr/bin/time date` return three differently formatted outputs)

Comment: You can also use `type time` to find out where a command is coming from :-)